# jQuery Selectors in list <li>

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Can somebody advise me with jQuery selectors.

I have a HTML list (see below) with four flag images in it. When a user rolls over a flag for example italy, I want it to fade out all the other three flags to 50% opacity.

```
<ul id="flags">
    <li id="German"><img src="images/flag_german.jpg" /></li>
    <li id="Italian"><img src="images/flag_italian.jpg" /></li>
    <li id="Spanish"><img src="images/flag_spanish.jpg" /></li>
    <li id="French"><img src="images/flag_french.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#flags li').hover(function() {
        $(this).siblings().stop(true).animate({opacity:'0.5'},1000);
    }, function() {
        $(this).siblings().stop(true).animate({opacity:'1'},1000);
    });
});
```

By using stop you help prevent the state where you have rolled over alot of elements and they have queued up animations.  It clears all the current animations in the queue for the element and assigns the new one.

The reason you need to use animate rather then fadeIn and fadeOut is because of a [weird bug with fadeIn/fadeOut and the hover event](http://blog.petersendidit.com/post/jquery-hover-with-a-fade/).  Haven't figured out what causes the bug though.

Comment: +1 for hover and not leaving the elements faded when you stop hovering over the entire collection.

Answer (score 6):

What about someting like this (not tested)

```
   $("#flags li").mouseover(function(){
      var id = this.id;
      $("#flags li").not("#"+id).animate({opacity:'0.5'},1000);
      $(this).animate({opacity:'1'},1000);
    });
```

Comment: Cheers seth... lemme try it out!

rgds
D

Comment: I just fixed a typo.  The solution is all mkoryak

Comment: If you roll over all the li's quickly you will see it continue to fade each one even after you have stopped moving the mouse.  My answer will work correctly in this case.

Comment: Thats great. That is what I was searching for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#flags li').bind('mouseover', function() {
    $('#flags li').not($(this)).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
}).bind('mouseout', function() {
    $('#flags li').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [siblings selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/siblings).

Comment: Thanks everyone! Got it to work, looks great! Can't wait to get up to speed with jQuery! ...it's amazing!

Thanks again
Decbrad